# Get ClickedItem from a ListView (using MVVM)

Tags: listview, mvvm, windows-8, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I have a ListView in a Windows Universal Application, described as follows:

```
ListView ItemsSource="{Binding RecentlyAddedTvSeriesEpisodes}"
         IsItemClickEnabled="True" SelectionMode="Single"
         x:Name="listOfThings">

         <!--Behaviour for item click-->
         <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
             <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="ItemClick">
                 <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding VideoItemClickCommand}" 
             CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=listOfThings, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
             </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
         </i:Interaction.Behaviors>                   

         <!--ListView template for all items-->
         <ListView.ItemTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
             ...
             </DataTemplate>
         </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

If I click on an item, the behaviour is to invoke a relay command and pass as a `CommandParameter` the `SelectedItem` property of the ListView.

**If no item is selected in the ListView, it passes the `ItemClickEventArgs` object**. From this, I can easily get the clicked item:

```
private async void ExecuteItemClickCommand(ItemClickEventArgs parameter)
{
    //Get the clicked item
    Model.VideoModel selectedVideo = parameter.ClickedItem as VideoModel;
}
```

**If an item is selected in the ListView, it passes to the RelayCommand the `SelectedItem` property (directly the model) even if I click on other item rather than the selected one.**

I would like to find out how to get the **`ClikedItem`** of a `ListView`, regardless the selected items in the `ListView`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to get it through the behavior, but how about simply handling the event in code behind and invoking the command from there? You'll probably save 3 lines of code and a a few kBs of binary size...